# struts 2 : Capturing modifications to a guava table (TreeBasedTable) in action

Tags: dictionary, struts2, guava, ognl

There is an object (ObjectA) which has another object inside (ObjectB). There is a `Guava TreeBasedTable` inside the Object B. This Table has a string as row-key,column-key and another object "ObjectC" as value. This table has been displayed on the jsp using the `<s:iterator/>` and `<s:textfield/>` tags and it is being displayed correctly (the "values" inside the `<s:textfield/>` are correct but the "names" are not).

Now, the problem arises when the `<s:textfield/>` is modified. How do we capture the modified values inside ObjectC in the action class?

```java
public class ObjectA implements Serializable {
private Integer attr1;
private List<ObjectB> objB;
//...getters and setters....
public class ObjectB implements Serializable {
private Integer attr11;
private Table<String,String,ObjectC> allPFields;
// ...getters and setters....
public class ObjectC implements Serializable {
private Integer attr111;
public String attr112;
// ...getters and setters....
```

**jsp code:**

```
<!-- language: lang-html -->

<s:iterator value="#objB.allPlainFields.row(#rowKey)" var="fieldMap"
    status="fieldStatus">
    <li><label><s:property value="#fieldMap.key" /></label><span>
            <s:textfield name="<NOT SURE>" value="%{#fieldMap.value.attr12}" />
    </span></li>
</s:iterator>
```

A `TreeBasedTable` in `Guava` is similar to a map inside a map, I tried doing `allPFields[#outerkey][#innerkey].attr112` but, it didn't work.

The object structure when the screen is displayed with existing values in the database

```
<!-- language: lang-java -->
objA        
objBList    ArrayList<E>  (id=668)  
elementData Object[10]  (id=7438)   
    [0] objB  (id=7439) 
        allPFields  TreeBasedTable<R,C,V>  (id=7443)    
            backingMap  TreeMap<K,V>  (id=8116) 
            cellSet null    
            columnComparator    NaturalOrdering  (id=503)   
            columnKeySet    null    
            columnMap   null    
            factory TreeBasedTable$Factory<C,V>  (id=8117)  
            rowKeySet   null    
            rowKeySet   StandardRowSortedTable$RowKeySortedSet  (id=8118)   
            rowMap  StandardRowSortedTable$RowSortedMap  (id=8119)  
            rowMap  null    
            values  null
```

And the "allPFields" looks like the following in action:

```
{OuterKey1=
    {InnerKey1=ObjectC[attr111=31, attr112=Hi there], 
     InnerKey2=ObjectC[attr111=40, attr112=How are you]
    }
 }
```

The "allPFields" value above has been picked up from the IDE console.

Answer (score 0):

As I told you in your other question, I've never used `Guava TreeBasedTable`;

However, according to the [Official Guava Documentation](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#Table), a

> `TreeBasedTable` , which `is essentially backed by a TreeMap<R, TreeMap<C, V>>`

and the [`get` method](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/TreeBasedTable.html#row%28R%29) is

> `V get(Object rowKey, Object columnKey)`
>
> Returns the value corresponding to the given row and column keys, or null if no such mapping exists.

In `Java` it would be:

```
Object value = objA.getObjB().get(listIndex).getAllPlainFields.get(rowKey, columnKey).getAttr112;
value = "new value";
```

Then in `OGNL` you could try something (totally untested) like:

```
<s:textfield value="%{#fieldMap.value.attr12}"
 name="objA.objB[#fieldStatus.index].allPlainFields.get(#rowKey, #fieldMap.Key).attr112"  />
```

P.S: **BEWARE OF TYPO**... you are using `allPlainFields` and `allPFields` together... one of them is wrong, make sure that all the notations point to the right variable name.

P.P.S: I don't know your requirements, but this structure seems a little "over-designed" to me... it definitely does not respect the `KISS paradigm` :)

Comment: Tried this but didn't work:                                     `    <s:textfield name="objA.objB[%{#fieldStatus.index}].allPlainFields.get('%{#rowKey}','%{#fieldMap.key}').attr112" value="%{#fieldMap.value.attr112}"  />` ....somehow, I have not been able to make methods work using OGNL. The moment I use a method, the object (ObjB) is sent as null.

Comment: Ahh... have you disabled `Dynamic Method Invocation` in Struts.xml (if yes, re-enable it)? Have you verified if the getter in `ObjectB` is `getAllPFields` or `getAllPlainFields` ?

Comment: Yes, `Dynamic Method Invocation` was set to false..I have enabled it...let me check now.

Comment: Still objB is null in the action...the `<s:textfield>` is rendered as  `<input type="text" id="review-act_objA_objB_0__allPlainFields_get('rowKey1',' column_key1')_attr112" value="correct value" name="objA.objB[0].allPlainFields.get('rowKey1',' column_key1').attr112">`....Tried it with `row(rowkey)[columnkey]` as well.

Comment: The following code brings a nonNull `objB` in action but the `allPlainfields` is still `NULL`. The code: `objA.objB[%{#fieldStatus.index}].allPlainFields['%{rowKey}']['%{#fieldMap.key}'].attr112`.....any further clues? I understand about your complexity statement...We need to display a table on the screen (Map,Map)and hence the choice....

Comment: it is allPlainFields. sorry missed it.

Comment: another interesting thing. If I define a `textfield` as follows, the value is correctly displayed. That means, the `value` attribute takes method but the `name` doesn't. `<s:textfield name="tempVal" value="%{objA.objB[0].allPlainFields.row('OuterKey1')['InnerKey1'].attr112}"  />`

Comment: moving ahead: the following code in the iterator does display correct value but when the value is modified and submitted, the objB in `action` is still null. Please note that, the `value` attribute has not been mentioned for the `textfield`. That means, the `name` attribute is sufficient to display the `value`. `<s:textfield name="objA.objB[%{#fieldStatus.index}].allPlainFields.row('%{rowKey}')['%{#fieldMap.key}'].attr112" />`

Comment: Do you have default (no args) constructors in your Objects ? I mean, explicit definition OR no other consctructors definition ? Maybe something is preventing the object to be correctly instantiated by OGNL...

Comment: `ObjectA`, `ObjectB` and `ObjectC` have `no args constructor`. However, the `TreeBasedTable` has to be created using  `TreeBasedTable.create()`. Could this be an issue?

Comment: Absolutely yes. But I'm conducting some experiments using `TreeMap<String, TreeMap<String,String>>` and it is not working the same. I'm afraid the problem is in the double casting... stay tuned.

Comment: Currently looking at issues at apache jira: [link]https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WW-3866   [link]https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/OGNL-221

Comment: Nice... I'm currently using that version (2.3.1.2), affected by the problem, and tried with a TreeMap, as in the Jira. Try upgrading S2 (for test purposes) and using nested Treemap instead of Guava stuff, that adds the problem of the .create() method... let us know

Comment: Tried with a TreeMap<String, List<ObjectC>> but facing an issue. [http://stackoverflow.com/q/15006868/2087216]